# Unity C# - Custom #if Preprocessor macro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to achieve something and can't find a solution :

I want to make a little chunk of code (actually a class) that will handle InApp Purchase functions, to do so I need the **UnityEngine.Purchasing** include.

The fact is I don't always have this, and I want my class to be read only if I have access to this include : If Unity In-App Purchasing service is on.

I know we can specify some code to be comment with the platform dependant #if. And I tried to follow [this link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Custom_Defines_Manager) to handle it with a specific file (that should be add only if you have the unity IAP service enable).

```
private static List<AssetDefine> CustomDefines = new List<AssetDefine> {
    new AssetDefine ("UnityPurchasing.m", new BuildTargetGroup[] { BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, BuildTargetGroup.Android, BuildTargetGroup.iOS, BuildTargetGroup.Unknown }, "UnityIAP_Enabled"),
};
```

Here is the current "AssetDefine" and

```
#if UnityIAP_Enabled
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
#endif
```

Here is how I try to use it. My Unity Editor informs me that

> "the type or namespace name 'Purchasing' does not exist in the
>   namespace UnityEngine"

I'm not sure if there is another way to define a custom #if in order to allow my code to always be here but not always be taken into account while trying to compile.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried placing "UnityIAP_Enabled" in surrounding brackets?

Comment: @cmprogram it's a preprocessor directive, it is correct like that. Did you try to add the package "In app purchasing" in Window -> Package Manager

Comment: @Isma Fair enough. Could you implement a TRY-CATCH instead of an IF? e.g. Try { if(UnityIAP_ENABLED){using UnityEngine.Purchasing;} } Catch { Debug.log('No purchasing implemented'); return; }

Comment: No, try-catchs are evaluated during run-time so it will not help, the code won't even compile. He has to make sure the directive UnityIAP_Enabled is defined when that library is not available.

Comment: That's correct ! And @Isma I just did to see if there is any difference but It does not change anything, actually it seems that UnityEngine.Purchasing is not recognized even now. I suppose it's recognize only if I put "In-App Purchasing" services ON ? Actually if there is any way to get the UnityEngine.Purchasing directly within my code It could do it to (and the code would always be valid, unity service ON or OFF)

Comment: I made an answer, hope it helps...

Comment: Why not create 2 configurations for the project, one with and the other without conditional compilation symbols and then surround the code that differs in both versions with preprocessor directive checking if this symbols are present for given configuration and build? Its not the best solution but thats how we do it in our company in legacy projects

Comment: @kuskmen, that’s easy in visual studio, I'm not sure if it can be done using Unity, it is a good solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace imports are resolved at compile time so you need to make sure the assembly containing the namespace is referenced by your project.

You can use conditional preprocessor directives to build different versions of your app (game in this case) with or without a given reference but you need to make sure that the version you are building matches the preprocessor directive and whether it contains the reference assembly or not, for example:

**Case 1 - Build a version that do not support "In App purchases"**

1. Remove the package "In app purchasing" in Window -> Package Manager  in Unity.
2. Define a preprocessor directive for case 1 (this must be present before any "using" directive or any code using the in app purcharsing classes.

`#undef UnityIAP_Enabled`

3. Wrap the code using #if directives, the code within the block will be ignored during compilation (it will not be even part of your executable, thus, reducing the size of your game)

```
    #if UnityIAP_Enabled
    using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
    #endif
```

4. Build the game.

**Case 2 - Build a version of the app (game) that supports "In App purchases"**

Now you do the opposite

1. Add the package "In app purchasing" in Window -> Package Manager in Unity.
2. Define preprocessor directive for case 2

`#define UnityIAP_Enabled`

3. Build the game.

**Edit**

You can avoid manually setting the defines in your code by using platform custom #defines as specified here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But do I need to write the #undef and #define each time I want to switch between those two? 
Is it possible to make it file / package dependant? (If Unity founds the file or package it #define it, else it #undef it ?) That's what I'm trying to achieve, the goal is to make it automatic, or at least to get an editor checkmark to chose whether or not it should be define.

Comment: What's the point of making it automatic? This is not evaluated at run-time, either you make a version with or without support for purchasing but it is a decision you make at compile time and you know if you have the package or not, right? You could also made a script to check for the package files and change it automatically, for example, using Python or a bat or sh file and running it before each build but I am not sure it is worth the hassle.

Comment: The core objective of it is to never manually change the #define for anything else. I need to send the code to other people without needing them to update it by hand. If there is no solution it will be the case but if I'm able to avoid it it's preferable.

Comment: You can have several build configs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html see how to set custom defines in that page, if you do it there, you don´t need to set it in code. I will update my answer too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see what I can do with all that !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch through the menu

```
public static class DefineSwitcher
{
    private const string DEFINE_NAME = "MY_CUSTOM_DEFINE";
    private readonly static BuildTargetGroup[] _buildingGroups = new BuildTargetGroup[] { BuildTargetGroup.Android, BuildTargetGroup.iOS, BuildTargetGroup.Standalone };

    [MenuItem("Window/Define/Add")]
    public static void AddDefine()
    {
        DefineManager.AddCompileDefine(DEFINE_NAME, _buildingGroups);
    }

    [MenuItem("Window/Define/Remove")]
    public static void RemoveDefine()
    {
        DefineManager.RemoveCompileDefine(DEFINE_NAME, _buildingGroups);
    }
}

public static class DefineManager
{
    public static void AddCompileDefine(string newDefineCompileConstant, BuildTargetGroup[] targetGroups = null)
    {
        if (targetGroups == null)
            targetGroups = (BuildTargetGroup[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(BuildTargetGroup));

        foreach (BuildTargetGroup grp in targetGroups)
        {
            if (grp == BuildTargetGroup.Unknown)        //the unknown group does not have any constants location
                continue;

            string defines = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(grp);
            if (!defines.Contains(newDefineCompileConstant))
            {
                if (defines.Length > 0)         //if the list is empty, we don't need to append a semicolon first
                    defines += ";";

                defines += newDefineCompileConstant;
                PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(grp, defines);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveCompileDefine(string defineCompileConstant, BuildTargetGroup[] targetGroups = null)
    {
        if (targetGroups == null)
            targetGroups = (BuildTargetGroup[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(BuildTargetGroup));

        foreach (BuildTargetGroup grp in targetGroups)
        {
            string defines = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(grp);
            int index = defines.IndexOf(defineCompileConstant);
            if (index < 0)
                continue;           //this target does not contain the define
            else if (index > 0)
                index -= 1;         //include the semicolon before the define
                                    //else we will remove the semicolon after the define

            //Remove the word and it's semicolon, or just the word (if listed last in defines)
            int lengthToRemove = Math.Min(defineCompileConstant.Length + 1, defines.Length - index);

            //remove the constant and it's associated semicolon (if necessary)
            defines = defines.Remove(index, lengthToRemove);

            PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(grp, defines);
        }
    }
}
```